# Python-setattr pass function with args

Tags: python, class, lambda, setattr

I'm trying to set methods of a class programmatically by calling `setattr` in a loop, but the reference I pass to the function that is called by this method defaults back to its last value, instead of what was passed at the time of the `setattr`call. Curiously, I'm also setting the `__doc__` attribute and this assignment actually works as expected:

```
class Foo2:

    def do_this(self, pass_this: str):
        print(pass_this)


class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.reference = "ti-hihi"
        self.foo2 = Foo2()
        for (method_name, pass_this) in [("bar", "passed-for-bar"), ("bar2", "passed-for-bar2")]:
            my_doc = f"""my_custom_docstring: {pass_this}"""

            def some_func():
                self.foo2.do_this(pass_this=pass_this)
            some_func.__doc__ = my_doc
            setattr(self, method_name, some_func)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Foo()
    f.bar()  # prints "pass-for-bar2" instead of "pass-for-bar"
    f.bar.__doc__  # prints "pass-for-bar" as expected
```

I already tried a few things but couldn't figure it out.

Things I tried:

lambda -- my best bet, tbh

```
def some_func(reference):
    self.foo2.do_this(pass_this=reference)
some_func.__doc__ = my_doc
setattr(self, method_name, lambda: some_func(pass_this))
```

deepcopy

```
import copy

def some_func():
    self.foo2.do_this(pass_this=copy.deepcopy(pass_this))
some_func.__doc__ = my_doc
setattr(self, method_name, some_func)
```

another deepcopy variant which feels dangerous if I think about the place I want to put this:

```
import copy

def some_func():
    self.foo2.do_this(pass_this=pass_this)
some_func.__doc__ = my_doc
setattr(self, method_name, copy.deepcopy(some_func))
```

... and a few combinations of those but I'm missing some crucial piece.

Comment: To include an argument as part of the function I think you need to use something like importing `functools` and using `partial`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @AndrewAllaire for this tip, using `functools.partial` solved it for me

```
some_func = partial(self.foo2.do_this, pass_this=pass_this)
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods are class attributes, so `some_func` needs to be attached to `type(self)`, not `self` itself.

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.reference = "ti-hihi"
        self.foo2 = Foo2()
        for (method_name, pass_this) in [("bar", "passed-for-bar"), ("bar2", "passed-for-bar2")]:
            my_doc = f"""my_custom_docstring: {pass_this}"""

            def some_func(self):
                self.foo2.do_this(pass_this=pass_this)
            some_func.__doc__ = my_doc
            setattr(type(self), method_name, some_func)
```

As such, the `__init_` method is not really the proper place to do this, as you'll be repeatedly attaching the (effectively same) methods to the class every time you instantiate the class. A class decorator would be more appropriate:

```
def add_methods(cls):
    for (method_name, pass_this) in [("bar", "passed-for-bar"), ("bar2", "passed-for-bar2")]:
        my_doc = ...
        def some_func(self):
            self.foo2.do_this(pass_this=pass_this)
        some_func.__doc__ = my_doc
        setattr(cls, method_name, some_func)
    return cls


@add_methods
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.reference = "ti-hihi"
        self.foo2 = Foo2()
```

`add_methods` doesn't really require any special information about `Foo`. Indeed, `add_methods` can be applied to any class that

1. Defines a `foo2` attribute for its instances, and
2. `foo2` has a type that provides an appropriate `do_this` method.

Even that assumption can be made more explicit by defining a suitable base class.

```
def FooBase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo2 = Foo2()

@add_methods
def Foo(FooBase):
    pass
```

Now you can simply state that `add_methods` is designed to work with subclass of `FooBase`.

Comment: result seems to be the same with type(self) instead of self (+ self in the signature). Also there's a reason I'm doing it in the __init__ method, and while I agree it's not as efficient, instantiating is easier than the refactoring I have to do otherwise

Comment: Problems can start to arise if you use inheritance. A callable instance attribute is not the same thing as an instance method.

Comment: that's good to know - in my actual use-case I'm calling this from a base class that I'm not planning on inheriting to anyone, so fingers crossed that it'll be fine